# How to optimize an algorithm with multiple while loops?

Tags: java, algorithm, while-loop

I am trying to solve a problem on leetcode.com [Ugly Number II](https://leetcode.com/problems/ugly-number-ii/).

**problem:** An ugly number is a positive integer whose prime factors are limited to 2, 3, and 5.

Given an integer n, return the nth ugly number.

**example:**

Input: n = 10
Output: 12
Explanation: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12] is the sequence of the first 10 ugly numbers.

This is my solution

```
class Solution {
    public int nthUglyNumber(int n) {
        int outputNumber = 6;
        int temp = 1;
        if (n < 7) {
            return n;
        }
        int i = 7;
        while (i != (n + 1)) {
            outputNumber = outputNumber + 1;
            temp = outputNumber;
            while (temp % 5 == 0) {
                temp = temp / 5;
            }
            while (temp % 2 == 0) {
                temp = temp / 2;
            }
            while (temp % 3 == 0) {
                temp = temp / 3;
            }
            if (temp == 1) {
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        return outputNumber;
    }
}
```

this works for small numbers, but when the input is a big number, then I have **Time Limit Exceeded**
The question is how to optimize this code?

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] the post and format the code properly.

Comment: Division (and modulo) operations are the slowest basic mathematical operations, taking up to 40-80 times longer than additions. So you could try to 'construct' those ugly numbers by multiplication or addition. Or, as a more direct approach like yours: save all the numbers you have already processed in an array, and in your while loops check if those numbers have already been identified. This way for large numbers you save a lot of time, but it costs RAM.

Comment: Isn't `while(temp%5==0){temp=temp/5;}` the same as `temp/(floor(log5(temp))*5)`?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A051037

Comment: @user1984 It is not.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You're looking for numbers of the form 2<sup>a</sup>×3<sup>b</sup>×5<sup>c</sup> for non-negative integers a, b, c. Instead of looking for ugly numbers, wouldn't it be easier to just generate them?

Comment: Is there a good way to add LaTeX? I'm new to overflow and I know the math stack exchange has LaTeX support.

Comment: I don't think it's supported here. You could use codecogs using a non-transparent background, but in this simple case I think it's best to just use a little HTML. I've edited, but feel free to undo/rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I used two tricks to make it about twice as fast, but it's still far too slow. I suspect the check-all-integers-for-ugliness approach is hopeless, and you'll find faster approaches in the discussions on LeetCode.

```
class Solution {
    public int nthUglyNumber(int n) {
        for (int i = 1; true; i++)
            if (1418776204833984375L % (i / (i & -i)) == 0)
                if (--n == 0)
                    return i;
    }
}
```

The two tricks:

- `i & -i` extracts the lowest 1-bit, so dividing by that takes out every factor 2.
- 1418776204833984375 is 3<sup>19</sup>×5<sup>13</sup>. Every positive `int` with only factors 3 and 5 divides that, and every other positive `int` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to just maintain a collection of ugly numbers that we will need to visit.  We start with a collection containing just `1`, and then at each step, we remove the lowest value, and add the values found by multiplying our lowest value by `2`, by `3`, and by `5`.  Since these may be duplicates (`24 = 8 * 3` and `24 = 12 * 2`) but we only want them once apiece, our collection should be a Set.

My Java is far too rusty, but here's a JavaScript implementation that you could use as pseudocode:

```js
const ugly = (count) => {
  const upcoming = new Set ([1])
  const found = []
  while (found .length < count) {
    const next = Math .min (...upcoming .values ())
    found .push (next)
    upcoming .delete (next)
    upcoming .add (2 * next) 
    upcoming .add (3 * next) 
    upcoming .add (5 * next)
  }
  return found
}

const uglies = ugly (1690) // This was the upper bound specified in the problem

const nthUglyNumber = (n) =>  uglies [n - 1]

console .log (nthUglyNumber (10))
console .log (nthUglyNumber (1690))
```

`ugly` finds the first `count` ugly numbers, returning them as an Array.  Internally, it keeps two collections.  `upcoming` is the ugly numbers we know we would eventually hit.  `found` is an array of numbers we have actually reached, always taking the smallest of the `upcoming` values.  When we select the next one, we remove it from `upcoming` and add to `upcoming` its `2`-, `3`-, and `5`-multiples.

This could be modified to be our only function.  But it's nice to call it once for our top value, and store the resulting array, as `uglies`.  Then `nthUglyNumber` is a simple function that extracts the value at the correct index.